# Extracting Data from People Picker in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to build a custom list where I have people's names and email addresses in two different columns.  Since I'm hooked up the the active directory, I would like to select the person's name from the AD and then have their email address automatically populate in another column.

The only way I have figured out to do this is to find the person's name twice in the active directory, first in the "Name" column and secondly in the "Email" column (which is formatted to show the person's email).  Can I do this with only having to enter the data in once.  It would be so much easier since I have to add hundreds of names to the list.

Also, and this is probably a little bit harder, the title of the row is the person's name and right now I have to manually enter it, but can it be automatically populated based on the people picker name selected from the AD?

Dave

Comment: This is a good question but I think it would be better to ask this on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com as it may not require a programming solution and you will probably get a better response over there.